# Swedish Saas e-commerce solution with nice API and integration with Klarna

Tags: api, rest, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I'm helping a Swedish LGBT bookstore/community center with their web presence. They've had a Wordpress-blog, a Facebook group and a Shopify-store for a few years. They have a lot of people coming to their live events and lots of people in their different Facebook groups/pages/personas, and on their mailing list. Business in the online store however is pretty slow.

My grand vision for them is to have a web presence where all the parts are more tightly integrated. At least the end user should be able to put an item in the shopping cart by clicking a button on the blog. I've done stuff in Wordpress before and I'm not to crazy about it. My plan now is to use Django as a foundation instead.

From a developer perspective Shopify seems like a nice solution. But the client wants to ditch Shopify in favor of a Swedish provider called Textalk. The client feels that a Swedish e-commerce provider, that integrates nicely with Swedish payment gateways that their Swedish customers are familiar with, would increase sales. Textalk can give them that. The bad thing about Textalk is that it lacks an API, so it will be pretty hard to do custom integration between store and blog.

Now I'm looking for alternatives that will give the clients what they want (brand recognition among Swedish customers) and me what I want (low risk of lock in, easy to use API, active developer community, good documentation).

Unfortunately Shopify seems to be out of the game because they don't integrate with any of the big Swedish payment gateways.

Klarna is a Swedish payment gateway that seems to have a pretty large market share. At least a lot of the stores I shop in use them. They also have what looks like a solid API, and at least one other [SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346012/marthin) has deemed it developer friendly. Maybe I shouldn't get to hung up on that since I don't plan to interact directly with Klarna anyway. But somehow I have a good feeling about them. And maybe at some point in the future I decide to interact directly with them from Django.

Klarna lists [a number of e-commerce solutions](http://integration.klarna.com/en/modules/step-by-step) that integrate with their API.

- Demandware
- Magento (both community and enterprise editions)
- OpenCart
- osCommerce
- Oxid
- Prestashop
- Übercart
- VirtueMart
- WP E-commerce
- XT-commerce
- ZenCart

Since there are no Django products on that list I can't go for an all Django solution. What I'll probably want to do instead is set up one of the above products, or better still buy it as Saas, and hook into that from the Django blog. So now all I have to do is figure out which of the above products in turn have nice RESTful APIs and are provided as Saas. I know that Prestashop is sold as Saas by Swedish company Prestaworks, but I can't seem to find anything on Prestashops own API.

What about the others? Any other users out there (preferably Swedish) that can give me a low down on them? Or do I have to work my way down the list and research them all be myself?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned that Klarna integrates with number of eCommerce Apps such as Magento, VirtueMart, etc.

Surely these Apps uses its (Klarna's) API.

You are fond of Django, why dont you go on writing your own python/django script referring the api's that are called by these ecommerce applications?

What their's (Magento/Virtuemart/etc.) PHP scripts can do, you can do the same with your python/Django code?